# Why function len() in arcpy mismatch with in fact

Tags: python, arcgis, arcpy

I would like to know I use the function `len()` in Arcpy and why the values that return does not match the fact.

from the function, len returns 12 but in fact list fields have 21. Please see my code

```
big=arcpy.ListFields('ลพบุรี_PSU_Select')
boss=len(big)
print(boss)
```

[image]

I would like to len function return follow true

Comment: Okay, the GUI says there are 21 object id's, but listFields is returning 12. Why do you think ListFields should return the 21 objects? Did you check the [documentation](https://pro.arcgis.com/en/pro-app/latest/arcpy/functions/listfields.htm) Can you tell which fields are being missed?

Answer (score 2):

The caption "1 of 21 selected" refers to the number of **features** (rows). There are 21 features in layer, and one of them is selected.

In contrast, the `ListFields` function is meant to return all the **fields** (columns) of the layer. This layer has 12 fields (OBJECTID, SHAPE, PSUNUM, ...).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get the amount of the features\rows you can use the GetCount method as follows:

```
rows_amount = int(arcpy.management.GetCount('ลพบุรี_PSU_Select').getOutput(0))
```

The `ListFields` function returns a list of the fields for a specified feature class, which is likely to have 12 fields.